# Which symbol represents which AI?

Tags: space-rangers-hd

Its been a while since I played Space Rangers 2 and now I'm playing the HD remake. I don't exactly remember which symbol represented which of the 3 AI factions.

They factions are:

- Kelleroid
- Blazeroid
- Terronoid

I have a Transfactorial Beacon that can summon Kelleroids and I want to do it in a Blazeroid/Terronoid system to make them fight each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dominator AI type images taken from the russian Wiki ([careful, it contains spoilers](http://wiki.snk-games.ru/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)):

Blazer: http://wiki.snk-games.ru/images/2EmBlazer.png

Keller: http://wiki.snk-games.ru/images/2EmKeller.png

Terron: http://wiki.snk-games.ru/images/2EmTerron.png

And their respective main ships, which are quite similar:

> http://wiki.snk-games.ru/images/Blazer.png http://wiki.snk-games.ru/images/Keller.png http://wiki.snk-games.ru/images/Terron_%28space%29.png

Comment: nice find, too bad I can't read russian so that wiki is useless to me.

Comment: Google translate FTW:   

https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.snk-games.net%2F%25D0%2594%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D1%258B&edit-text=